# Laravel - How to echo bunch of file as direct output

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using conditional include of css and js resource in laravel 5.4 framework using

```
Request::path();
```

I have created seperate css and js file for all the pages in project.

so obviously profile should not contain homepage css it doesn't make any sense here it is how i'm doing

```
if (Request::path() == 'homepage') {

    <script type="text/javascript" src="hppg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="homepgsupport.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="homepage-slider.css" />

} else if (Request::path() == 'profile') {

    <script type="text/javascript" src="profile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="profile-friends.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="profile-tag.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="profile.css" />

}
```

**Is it possible i can echo resource from laravel controller ?**

let's say i can create controller for js and it include file in argument

for example

```
<script src="http://mywebsitename.com/js/<?php echo Request::path();?>"></script>
```

i did try but i dont know how to echo plain resource in controller

what should be my controller code is there any function in laravel which can echo the file containt

Comment: You can do something like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ Request::path().'.css' }}"/>` if you want to include `'profile.css'` on profile page and so on...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AkshayKhale but my file name is not same as path name and it contains more than one file

Comment: Then you can pass all the file names in an Array to Blade file using `return view('myblade.blade.php', compact('css_file_names');` and in blade file you can load those files using `@foreach($css_file_names as $file_name) <link href="{{ $file_name }}" /> @endforeach`

Comment: may be you didn't read the question completely (i don't want my code to be hulk) it should include using one line